# Creating an intro followed by a loop

Tags: flash, actionscript, loops

I just recorded some song and cut it into two parts. The first part contains an intro and the second is supposed to loop. What I want to do now, is to have a simple graphical animation (5 keyframes or so) that loops as well, while the music plays along. 
There's probably a simple solution to it, when you're familiar with AS. Unfortunately this is the first thing I've ever tried to do with Flash.
I'm using Flash CS4.

Greetings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the simplest way would probably to do this on the timeline if you don't have any ActionScript experience.

You don't even have to split up your music file beforehand: just import your song onto the timeline.

Now create a new layer above the music. Name this layer "actions" and lock it. Create a keyframe on the actions layer on the very last frame. Click on this keyframe, go into your actions panel (Alt+F9), and type the code below, but replace the "1337" with the frame number where you would like the loop to start over:

```
gotoAndPlay(1337);
```

Now your flash movie will play the introduction once, and then loop the rest of it indefinitely.

All you need to do now is add your animation to the timeline and it will loop along with your music.